# Importing data from text file and saving the same in excel

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to read data from text file (which is output given by Tesseract OCR) and save the same in excel file. The problem i am facing here is the text files are in space separated format, and there are multiple files. Now i need to read all the files and save the same in excel sheet.
I am using MATLAB to import and export data. I even thought of using python to convert the files into CSV format so that i can easily import the same in MATLAB and simply excelwrite the same. But no good solution.
Any guidance would be of great help.

thank you

Comment: Do you just need to convert to CSV format?  That's an option under MATLAB's Import Wizard

Comment: Yes...if I can covert to csv then I think my problem should be solved.  Can u point the same. Because I went through help but wasn't able to find any converting tool like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a text file in Matlab you can use `fscanf` or `textscan` then to export to excel you can use `xlswrite` that write directly to the excel file.

Comment: Also there are multiple files. Which I need to read n keep updating on same excel sheet. On next line. Importing it in Matlab doesn't seem to be a problem. But I should be able to recognize every word separately. N which I think is possible only possible if its in csv format.

Comment: with `textscan` and `fscanf` you can separate the words also without the commas.
Then once the data are in Matlab you can do pretty much what you want with them

Comment: with text scan i am able to import the data. But when i try to save the data into excel sheet using xlswrite, it doesn't store anything.
I am sure i am able to import the data because i can see it using 
a = textscan(f,'%s','delimiter','\n')
celldisp(a),

Comment: It depends on how you want to put the data in the excel file.
Please refer to the Matlab user's guide here: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html

Comment: Well i partially achieved what i was looking for. Sorry for late reply. i wrote a small script to remove unwanted new lines and spaces and then simple "textscan" and "xlswrite" worked for me.